# Trouble understanding Functions in C

Tags: c, function, cs50

I am working through a programming assignment. I had the key validation working within main but decided to try to make it a separate function. I do not understand functions very well yet so I am unable to see where I am going wrong. Whenever I run the program, I always just get "Key is Valid" even when I know it's not. As I said, the program was running fine in main.

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int validate (int c, string v[]); //prototpe validate function

int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    int validate (int argc, string argv[]); //run validate for argc and argv

    printf("Key is valid\n"); //if valid, print message

}

int validate (int c, string v[])
{
    //Validate that only one Command Line Argument was entered
    if (c != 2) //Check the number if entered commands at execution
    {
        //If more than one, print error message
        printf("Key must be the only Command Line Argument\n");
        return 1; //Return false
    }

    //Validate that Key length is 26 characters
    if (strlen(v[1]) != 26) //Don't forget null 0
    {
        printf("Key must contain exactly 26 characters\n");
        return 1; //Return false
    }

    //Validate that all Key characters are alphabetic
    for (int i = 0, n = strlen(v[1]); i < n; i++)
    {
        //Check each element of the array
        if (isalpha(v[1][i]))
        {
            continue; //Continue if alphabetic
        }
        else
        {
            //if non-alphabetic, print error code
            printf("Key must contain only alphabetic characters\n");
            return 1; //Return false
        }
    }

    //Validate that each Key character is unique
    for (int x = 0, z = strlen(v[1]) - 1; x < z; x++)
    {
        //Create a second loop to compare every element to the first before incrementing the first
        for (int y = x + 1; y < z; y++)
        {
            //Cast array elements to int, check if each element equals next element in array
            if (v[1][x] == v[1][y])
            {
                printf("Key must contain exactly 26 unique characters\n");
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }

    return 0; //Key is valid, so return true
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are just declaring the function `validate` instead of running that and printing `Key is valid` unconditionally.

To run the function `validate` and print `Key is valid` only if it returns `0`, the `main` function should be like this:

```
int main (int argc, string argv[])
{
    if (validate (argc, argv) == 0) //run validate for argc and argv and check its response
    {
        // put printing inside if statement so that it runs only if the condition is true
        printf("Key is valid\n"); //if valid, print message
    }
}
```

Comment: That worked! Thank you. So running it as an if statement allows me to check the conditions, whereas if I were just running a function that, for example, did some math, I could just run that as I was doing and then my program would have the results of that function going forward? Or am I still messing that up. Just trying to get a better understanding.

Comment: @apreynolds1989 It is not clear that what "as I was doing" mean, but you cannot run functions by just declaring them.

Comment: You need to catch the return value of the function. Otherwise your code doesn't have the result of the function execution unless you are using pointers.

Comment: Okay. I thought by just calling the function it would run and then if that function returned a false at any point then it would end the program but I see that is not the case. Thank you both!

Comment: @apreynolds1989 **Calling** function will make the function run. **Declareing** function won't make the function run.

Answer (score 0):

Function declaration hints the compiler that I will return a particular data type and I will accept the given data types in the arguments section. For example,

```
int check(int a, int b); -> return type is int and the function will accept 2 integer parameters.
int mul(int a, float b); -> return type is int and the function will accept 1 integer parameter and 1 float.
void check(); -> returns nothing, accepts nothing
```

function calling is like your code is calling the function to execute.

```
int c = check(2, 3);
int b = mul(3, 0.12);
check();
```

Your function is returning some value. You have to get that value and execute rest of the code based on the value as below.

```
if (validate (argc, argv) == 0) {
    printf("key is valid");
} else {
    printf("key is not valid");
}
```

Comment: `void check();` is not telling anything about what it accept in C. `void check(void);` is telling that it accepts nothing.

Comment: @MikeCAT: Thanks for clarifying. But usually we will declare functions as void check(); if it is not accepting any parameters. Please correct me if I am wrong.